# Regular expression to detect symbol at end of line in multi-line field

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

Can anyone suggest a Regex expression to detect if a symbol is present at end of line in a multi line field?

e.g. expression should be able to find a match in input below where '+' is at end of line 2.

```
abcd
efgh+
xyz
```

However for below input, the expression should not find a match as '+' comes in middle of text

```
abcd
ef + gh
xyz
```

I tried using expression - `((|\n))[+]`  but that returns positive result in both cases.

I just need to find the tweak to this expression so that it finds match on '+' symbol for

```
abcd
efgh+
xyz
```

but does not find a match on '+' symbol for

```
abcd
ef + gh
xyz
```

Comment: Like `\+$` and enable multiline

Comment: Is there a way to do this without enabling multi line flag?

Comment: Why would you not want multiline? Try it like this `(?m)\+$`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but (?m) -> mode modifier is giving error. Is there a way to combine carriage return and Line feed commands - [\u000d\u000a] with \+$

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

```
/.+\+$/gm
```

It would be help to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there a way to make it work without global multi line flag i.e. gm?